# Cant get last array value

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I dont understand why my array gets cut in loop?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => order
            [value] => asd
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => item
            [value] => aa
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => quant
            [value] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => price
            [value] => 20
        )

)
```

My php code with for loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($json_array); $i++)
{
    echo $json_array[$i]['name'];
}
```

The result I'm getting is: `orderitemquant` but why last value `price` is gone? What is wrong with this code?

Comment: no error, warning on php error log?

Comment: whats the count of your array?

Comment: Are you sure $json_array is what you think it is? try printing out the array values first to make sure ``print_r($json_array);``

Comment: your code seems absolutely fine, are you absolutely sure the `$json_array` has `"price"` in the last element's name attribute? It could be echoing a blank value.

Comment: I get `orderitemquantprice` so you are misrepresenting something. There should be no spaces in your output for instance. Are you leaving out the logic that creates the space?

Comment: @Draiken My array in the OP code is `print_r($json_array);` result, so there is value price

Comment: @OsvaldaKazlaučiūnaitė try putting a `print_r($json_array)` inside the `for` loop to see if the `$json_array` variable is being changed.

Comment: @Esailija spaces I left writing code here for better view

Comment: @Draiken `print_r($json_array);` inside for loop also showing "price"

Comment: I give up, if this is the complete code, I have no idea how this can be happening

Comment: could you please provide the code where $json_array is filled respectively the output, if there is any, of json_last_error().

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `foreach`? In my opinion it suits better for iterating your array.

```
foreach($json_array as $sub_array) {
    echo $sub_array['name'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, off by one error:

```
for($i = 0; $i =< count($json_array); $i++)
{
    echo $json_array[$i]['name'];
}
```

Comment: Another answer with the same suggestion got too many negative votes and was deleted. There is no mistake in writing like the author of the question has written. It really depends on situation and there is no reason to add `=` sign to comparison as we are counting from **zero** to **three**. Your code counts from **zero** to **four**, which is definitely incorrect and will result in an error as `$json_array[5]['name']` does not exist. Your answer is only correct if you want to count from **one**.

Comment: Okay sorry, you're right. I'll let it be existing here so this won't be repeated!